# Ruby on rails: Disable submit button in form

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a newbie question. In the _form.html.erb, I want to disable my form, before user check the check box input. What is the best way to do that? Thx.
Here is my code:

```
<%= form_for(@seller) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

<%= check_box_tag 'terms' %> I accept the Terms and Conditions <br />
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try something like this,

write `onclick` event and you can do it.

```
   <%= check_box_tag 'terms',1,false,:onclick=>'handleClick(this);' %> I accept the Terms and Conditions <br />
```

in javascript:-

```
  <script>
  function handleClick()
   {
    if(document.getElementById('terms').checked)
     document.getElementById("Sign_up_id").disabled=true; // your submit button Id
    else
    document.getElementById("Sign_up_id").disabled=false;
   }
 </script>
```

Your could use `click` event.

Comment: If it's checked shouldn't it not be disabled?  Am I missing something, or do you just need to reverse the if else?

Comment: in default `submit_tag` should be `disable=true`. After that this code will work.